# python behavior of list modification in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, int

Why is the behaviour of the following two `for` loops over a `list` different?

In the first example I have a `list` of `int`: modify each element in the `for` loop and print the result. The change in value however is only within the loop scope.

```
In [1]: my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
In [2]: for e in my_list:
   ...:     e = e*2
   ...:     print e
   ...:     
Out [2]: 2
         4
         6
         8
         10
         12
         14
         16
         18
         20

In [3]: my_list
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

In the second example I have a `list` of `list`: modify each element in the `for` loop and print the result. **In this case however, the change in value is passed outside the loop scope.**

```
In [4]: my_list = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
In [5]: for e in my_list:
   ...:     e[0] = e[0] + 1
   ...:     e[1] = e[1] + e[0]
   ...:     print e
   ...:     
Out [5]: [2, 4]
         [4, 8]
         [6, 12]
         [8, 16]
         [10, 20]
In [6]: my_list
Out[6]: [[2, 4], [4, 8], [6, 12], [8, 16], [10, 20]]
```

> Why modifying an `int` is different from modifying a `list` entry
>   (since it is also an `int`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing `e[0] = e[0] + 1`, you are actually modifying the first element of the list `e`, i.e. the first list in the `my_list` list. You are not modifying the *reference* to the list, `my_list` still contains the same list objects (it's just the content of these objects that has been changed).

Doing `e = e*2`, on the other hand, does not modify `e`, it reassigns the `e` variable to a new integer, which is a result of the `e*2` expression.

To make it more clear, inspect what's going on with the built-in [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function:

```
>>> my_list = [1]  # shortened for the sake of example
>>> for e in my_list:
...     print 'BEFORE id(e)', id(e)
...     e = e*2
...     print 'AFTER id(e)', id(e)
... 
BEFORE id(e) 25364408
AFTER id(e) 25364384
```

You can see that variable `e` has been reassigned to a different object. Now, if you do what you did in your second example:

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2]]
>>> for e in my_list:
...     print 'BEFORE id(e)', id(e)
...     e[0] = e[0] + 1
...     e[1] = e[1] + e[0]
...     print 'AFTER id(e)', id(e)
... 
BEFORE id(e) 140680995671144
AFTER id(e) 140680995671144
>>> id(my_list[0])
140680995671144
```

You see that you were operating on the same object with ID 140680995671144 all the time, and that `my_list` still holds a *reference* to this same object, but it was the object's contents that were changed.

Comment: Does you answer imply that the two variables on the different sides of `e = e * 2` have a different memory location, whereas in `b[0] = b[0] + 1` it is still the same memory location? If so, I understand, but why is this implemented like this?

Comment: Yes, `b` still points to the same memory location and when you do b[0] = b[0] + 1, you modify the "first element" at that location, but the location of `b` itself remains unchanged. `my_list` only contains _references_ to its contents and still points to this now-changed list `b`, that's why you see the change after the loop ends.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it more obvious to see what is going on.What you need to know here is that lists do not contain their items directly, they contain _references_ to them.